# Apex class and visualforce page version number

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there any rule apex class and visualforce should have same version?

Comment: See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70387

Answer (score 4):

We have many cases where the Apex class(es) and the Visualforce page have different version numbers and have not hit any issues.

So in my experience, the answer to your question is **no**.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce release new features with every new release and increase API version. API version decides which features is accessible on VF page or Apex class. That is one thing.
Other thing I noticed if your VF page and corresponding Apex controller doesn't match apex:actionfunction doesn't work as expected.