# No such field ActivityOriginType even though returned through field map

Tags: apex, schema, describefieldresult

We have an all fields query that gets the field map from an object's describe in Apex. It then loops over the map and assembles a query.

In one clients org, the field map is spitting out `ActivityOriginType` on the Task, but then when the query goes, we get this:

`System.QueryException: No such column 'activityorigintype' on entity 'Task'.`

We had issues with things like `LastViewedDate` where the field map gave out that field, but it wasn't actually accessible because there wasn't a tab for the object. Enabling the `Enable Improved Caching of Org Schema` critical update fixed issues with `LastViewedDate` but apparently isn't fixing issues with this `ActivityOriginType` field.

Does anyone know where this field came from and how you can get around this? My concern with adding it to a set of fields to leave out of the query is: I don't know how many of these weird hidden fields exist on various objects or if new ones will be added so the set will continuously need updating.

Is there a way to just toss them out? Is there something that can be done in the org to fix this issue with this field without a new package?

Comment: This is likely a version skew issue. Make sure all of your classes are the exact same API version. See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/70389/2984) I wrote some time ago. Also, generally speaking, a "select all" method should be used sparingly, because it does cause issues like this, as well as heap exhaustion, etc.

Comment: Would `stripInaccessible` help here, or is this where a View All Data user can't access it?

Comment: One issue is I don't know where this field comes from or how you you get it to show up, which makes creating a fix pretty hard when I don't fully know if it will fix it (like stripInaccessible, or doing an isAccessible check). When I looped over the field map in the user's org that has this happening that field didn't even show up in developer console but apparently does in our Apex code.

Comment: And the trip from where it assembles the query based on field map to when it does the query is all v48. So if field map gives us ActivityOriginType where it gets field map it should be able to query it if it was possible to query that field as it isn't going through any api version changes